# Where does fosuser save users?

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I finished installing sonata-admin bundle + fosuser bundle.
after creating users using the command line , i found out that when i login using admin admin its gives me bad credentials , so after debugging for a while i found out that the fos:user:create save users to fos_user_user not user table .
how to fix this and make the fos:user:create save created users in user table .

here is a snippet of my config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    #user_class:     Sizar\JobeetBundle\Entity\SizarUser
    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group

sonata_user:
    class:                  # Entity Classes
        user:               Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

if needed any configs then i will add it in the comments below

the User.php class

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser {

    protected $id;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

the orm User file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
              http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

<entity name="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User" table="fos_user_user">

    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator strategy="AUTO" />
    </id>

</entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: Please paste you `Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User` in the question, so we can check the entity config

Comment: Ok, i had to ask first, but post also you entity mapping file (xml/yaml depends on what you use)

Comment: No I mean you mapping information. see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information. You can use annotation, xml or yaml to set the entity mapping info

Comment: for this entity i used xml , i will post it up in the question @acrobat

Answer (score 1):

You will have to update you mapping config, so that doctrine knows which table it is mapped to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping ...>

<entity name="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User" table="fos_user_user">
...
</entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Here you will need to update the "table" property to the correct database table. Possibly you will need to [recreate the database](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-7-update-your-database-schema).

See [FosUserBundle - Install docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#a-doctrine-orm-user-class) for further info about the setup of your entities for the usage with FosUserBundle